# How should Python virtual environment be handled on Azure?

Tags: python, django, azure, web-applications, python-venv

### Background

I want to set up
[an Azure Web Service](https://box-whiskers-demo.azurewebsites.net/)
with Django.
On my local machine that app runs error-free in a virtual environment.
(The virtual environment name, `deploydjango`,
is indicated leftmost in my prompt - after activating using `source deploydjango/bin/activate` in repo root folder - before starting the Django server).

The virtual environment is "documented" by `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

(As I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57667310/888033)
I `git push`'ed from my local machine to my
[GitHub repository](https://github.com/engelsmann/boxplot)
with the virtual environment activated.

#### Question

How come that Azure creates another virtual environment, `antenv`?

Would it be right to edit the appropriate line of the
[Oryx manifest](https://github.com/engelsmann/boxplot/blob/master/oryx-manifest.toml)
(Azure project root `/oryx-manifest.toml`) from

> `virtualEnvName="antenv"`

to

> `virtualEnvName="deploydjango"`

Or put in other words: **Do I need to** deploy my virtual environment to Azure or will the `requirements.txt` specification do the job?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440844/why-is-the-azure-app-service-django-deploy-keep-failing/46443085#46443085

Comment: Peter's answer should help you. The extension of the scm website has been upgraded, but the path can be found in cmd to store our package content.